# Every 10 minutes, something goes wrong with one of my SATA drives

Tags: kernel, hard-drive, sata, smart, udisks

I have a computer with an SSD drive (Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB) with Ubuntu, and an additional hard drive connected with SATA for storage. It seems that every 10 minutes, some sort of "housekeeping" task is tried and fails. I notice this as my music playback is paused for 10-15 seconds (the music files are stored on the large drive).

Also attached to the computer is another Samsung SSD with Windows on it, it's not mounted now.

This is from `/var/syslog`:

```
May 23 11:05:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1906.980500] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
May 23 11:05:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1906.980509] ata3.00: failed command: SMART
May 23 11:05:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1906.980519] ata3.00: cmd b0/d0:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 15 pio 512 in
May 23 11:05:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1906.980519]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 23 11:05:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1906.980523] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
May 23 11:05:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1906.980529] ata3: hard resetting link
May 23 11:06:03 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1912.352537] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
May 23 11:06:08 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1916.984603] ata3: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
May 23 11:06:08 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1916.984612] ata3: hard resetting link
May 23 11:06:13 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1922.324600] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
May 23 11:05:45 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 compiz[2302]: Promise rejected after context unloaded: Message manager disconnected
May 23 11:06:16 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 udisksd[2410]: Error performing housekeeping for drive /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/ST3000DM001_1CH166_W1F36D8L: Error updating SMART data: sk_disk_smart_read_data: Input/output error (udisks-error-quark, 0)
May 23 11:06:16 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1924.912719] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
May 23 11:06:16 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1924.914054] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 23 11:06:16 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 1924.914062] ata3: EH complete
```

I've googled around for "Error performing housekeeping for drive", but the results - other than being ancient - generally talk about USB-connected external drives.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 but had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.10.

---

Edit: Another log:

```
May 23 11:15:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2507.181566] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
May 23 11:15:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2507.181571] ata3.00: failed command: SMART
May 23 11:15:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2507.181575] ata3.00: cmd b0/d0:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 15 pio 512 in
May 23 11:15:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2507.181575]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 23 11:15:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2507.181577] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
May 23 11:15:58 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2507.181580] ata3: hard resetting link
May 23 11:16:04 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2512.549658] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
May 23 11:16:08 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2517.193715] ata3: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
May 23 11:16:08 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2517.193719] ata3: hard resetting link
May 23 11:16:13 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2522.517833] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
May 23 11:16:16 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 udisksd[2410]: Error performing housekeeping for drive /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/ST3000DM001_1CH166_W1F36D8L: Error updating SMART data: sk_disk_smart_read_data: Input/output error (udisks-error-quark, 0)
May 23 11:16:16 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2524.797881] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
May 23 11:16:16 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2524.799343] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 23 11:16:16 jobjorn-ubuntu-R5 kernel: [ 2524.799364] ata3: EH complete
```

---

Edit: Output of `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.10.0-21-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1CH166
Serial Number:    W1F36D8L
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0614bb1be
Firmware Version: CC27
User Capacity:    3 000 592 982 016 bytes [3,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue May 23 14:15:44 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Read SMART Data failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 2
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 26800 hours (1116 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00   4d+00:10:47.792  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00   4d+00:10:44.496  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00   4d+00:10:42.889  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00   4d+00:10:41.229  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00   4d+00:10:37.937  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 26799 hours (1116 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 02 9a 51 42 00   3d+22:59:18.647  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00   3d+22:59:18.160  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 02 99 51 42 00   3d+22:59:15.381  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00   3d+22:59:14.379  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00   3d+22:59:14.379  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16382         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

---

Edit: I don't know if it is of any interest, but here's the result of a prestanda test made in the Disks utility. It's in Swedish, sorry about that.

[image: Result of prestanda test made in the Disks utility]

Comment: What drives do you use? can you execute smartctl -a /dev/sdX where X is the drive letter?

Comment: @user61664 absolutely, the question has been edited.

Comment: `Error updating SMART data: sk_disk_smart_read_data: Input/output error` usually happens in defective drives.

Comment: @MichaelBay sounds reasonable, but why am I not experiencing any issues other than this unreasonably regular error?